# Where is Erlang used and why?

Tags: erlang

I would like to know a list of the most common application/websites/solutions where Erlang is used, **successfully or not**.

Explaining why it is used into a specific solution instead of others programming languages would be very much appreciated, too.

Listing BAD Erlang case studies (cases in which Erlang is misused) it would be interesting, as well.

Comment: The problem with BAD case studies is that they don't really get famous or see the light of the day.

Comment: WHATSAPP Uses Erlang ! Google it for details

Comment: [EMqtt](http://emqtt.io/) is a very popular MQTT broker and nowadays getting used so much in IoT, developed in **erlang** with 1 million user sustainability.

Comment: The best questions and answers get closed for this reason on stackoverflow. Sigh.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

From *Programming Erlang*:

[image]
<sub>(source: [google.com](http://bks8.books.google.com/books?id=Qr_WuvfTSpEC&printsec=frontcover&img=1&zoom=5&sig=ACfU3U2F4YY4KqO0vCuZ4WEZjdE2yFFvvg))</sub>

#### Many companies are using Erlang in their production systems:

• **Amazon** uses Erlang to implement SimpleDB, providing database services as a part
of the Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud (EC2).

• **Yahoo!** uses it in its social bookmarking service, Delicious, which has more than
5 million users and 150 million bookmarked URLs.

• **Facebook** uses Erlang to power the backend of its chat service, handling more than
100 million active users. 
 
• **WhatsApp** uses Erlang to run messaging servers, achieving up to 2 million connected users per server.

• **T-Mobile** uses Erlang in its SMS and authentication systems.

• **Motorola** is using Erlang in call processing products in the public-safety industry.

• **Ericsson** uses Erlang in its support nodes, used in GPRS and 3G mobile networks
worldwide.

#### The most popular open source Erlang applications include the following:

• The 3D subdivision modeler **Wings 3D**, used to model and texture polygon
meshes.

• The **Ejabberd** system, which provides an Extensible Messaging and Presence Protocol
(XMPP) based instant messaging (IM) application server.

• The **CouchDB** “schema-less” document-oriented database, providing scalability
across multicore and multiserver clusters.

• The **MochiWeb** library that provides support for building lightweight HTTP servers.
It is used to power services such as MochiBot and MochiAds, which serve
dynamically generated content to millions of viewers daily.

• **RabbitMQ**, an AMQP messaging protocol implementation. AMQP is an emerging
standard for high-performance enterprise messaging.

Comment: facebook switched away from erlang: https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/chat-stability-and-scalability/51412338919/ and https://www.quora.com/When-did-Facebook-switch-away-from-using-Erlang-for-Facebook-Chat

Comment: Can you update the broken link for the book?

Answer (score 88):

[ejabberd](http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/) is one of the most well know erlang application and the one I learnt erlang with.

I think it's the one of most interesting project for learning erlang because it is really building on erlang's strength. (However some will argue that it's not OTP, but don't worry there's still a trove of great code inside...)

**Why ?**

An XMPP server (like ejabberd) can be seen as a high level router, routing messages between end users. Of course there are other features, but this is the most important aspect of an instant messaging server. It has to route many messages simultaneously, and handle many a lot of TCP/IP connections.

So we have 2 features:

- handle many connections
- route messages given some aspects of the message

These are examples where erlang shines.

**handle many connections**

It is very easy to build scalable non-blocking TCP/IP servers with erlang. In fact, it was designed to solve this problem.
And given it can spawn hundreds of thousand of processes (and not *threads*, it's a share-nothing approach, which is simpler to design), ejabberd is designed as a set of erlang processes (which can be distributed over several servers) :

- client connection process
- router process
- chatroom process
- server to server processes

All of them exchanging messages.

**route messages given some aspects of the message**

Another very lovable feature of erlang is [pattern matching](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Erlang_Programming/Pattern_Matching).
It is used throughout the language.

For instance, in the following :

```
access(moderator, _Config)->  rw;
access(participant, _Config)->  rw;
access(visitor, #config{type="public"})->  r;
access(visitor, #config{type="public_rw"})->  rw;
access(_User,_Config)->  none.
```

That's 5 different versions of the `access` function.
Erlang will select the most appropriate version given the arguments received. (`Config` is a structure of type `#config` which has a `type` attribute).

That means it is very easy and much clearer than chaining `if/else` or `switch/case` to make business rules.

**To wrap up**

Writing scalable servers, that's the whole point of erlang. Everything is designed it making this easy. On the two previous features, I'd add :

- hot code upgrade
- [`mnesia`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/apps/mnesia/index.html), distributed relational database (included in the base distribution)
- [`mochiweb`](http://code.google.com/p/mochiweb/), on which most http erlang servers are built on
- binary support (decoding and encoding binary protocol easy as ever)
- a great community with great open source projects (`ejabberd`, `couchdb` but also [`webmachine`](http://bitbucket.org/justin/webmachine/wiki/Home), [`riak`](http://riak.basho.com/) and a slew of library very easy to embed)

**Fewer LOCs**

There is also [this article](http://www.metabrew.com/article/rewriting-playdar-c-to-erlang-massive-savings/) from Richard Jones. He rewrote an application from C++ to erlang: 75% fewer lines in erlang.

Comment: To be fair, almost any C++ code rewritten in a modern language would reduce the LOC.

Answer (score 55):

The list of most common applications for Erlang as been covered (CouchDb, ejabberd, RabbitMQ etc) but I would like to contribute the following.

The reason why it is used in these applications comes from the core strength of Erlang: managing application **availability**.

Erlang was built from ground up for the telco environment requiring that systems meet at least 5x9's availability (99.999% yearly up-time).  This figure doesn't leave much room for downtime during a year! For this reason primarily, Erlang comes loaded with the following features (non-exhaustive):

- **Horizontal scalability** (ability to distribute jobs across machine boundaries easily through seamless intra & inter machine communications). The built-in database (Mnesia) is also distributed by nature.
- **Vertical scalability** (ability to distribute jobs across processing resources on the same machine): SMP is handled natively.
- **Code Hot-Swapping**: the ability to update/upgrade code *live* during operations
- **Asynchronous**: the real world is async so Erlang was built to account for this basic nature. One feature that contributes to this requirement: Erlang's "free" processes (>32000 can run concurrently).
- **Supervision**: many different strategies for process supervision with restart strategies, thresholds etc. Helps recover from corner-cases/overloading more easily whilst still maintaining traces of the problems for later trouble-shooting, post-mortem analysis etc.
- **Resource Management**: scheduling strategies, resource monitoring etc.  Note that the default process scheduler operates with O(1) scaling.
- **Live debugging**: the ability to "log" into live nodes at will helps trouble-shooting activities. Debugging can be undertaken live with full access to any process' running state. Also the built-in error reporting tools are very useful (but sometimes somewhat awkward to use).

Of course I could talk about its functional roots but this aspect is somewhat orthogonal to the main goal (high availability).  The main component of the functional nature which contributes generously to the target goal is, IMO: "share nothing". This characteristic helps contain "side effects" and reduce the need for costly synchronization mechanisms.

I guess all these characteristics help extending a case for using Erlang in business critical applications.

**One thing Erlang isn't really good at**: processing big blocks of data.

Comment: Could you explain the following: "One thing Erlang isn't really good at: processing big blocks of data."

Comment: He means things like decoding mpeg data. There is too much numerical computation which Erlang is not optimized for. If the processing just involves shuffling big blocks of data from one place to another, then Erlang is quite good at it. (Files to TPC Sockets, etc)

Comment: You can't update shared blocks of data (there are no pointers in Erlang) and hence data must be shuttled across processes which in turn translate to inefficiencies.

Comment: As an aside, Ericsson, I believe, said Erlang achieved 9x9's availability.

Comment: We’re [contemplating](https://github.com/keean/zenscript/issues/41#issuecomment-407637790) improving upon the weakness of Erlang cited here.

Answer (score 20):

We built a [betting exchange](http://smarkets.com) (aka prediction market) using Erlang.  We chose Erlang over some of the more traditional financial languages (C++, Java etc) because of the built-in concurrency.  Markets function very similarly to telephony exchanges.  Our CTO gave a talk on our use of Erlang at [CTO talk](http://blog.smarkets.com/2009/07/03/smarkets-tech-talk-on-erlang/).

We also use CouchDB and RabbitMQ as part of our stack.

Comment: Just a note, the link to your talk is now private.

Answer (score 19):

Erlang comes from Ericsson, and is used within some of their telecoms systems.

Outside telecoms, [CouchDb](http://couchdb.apache.org/) (a document-oriented database) is possibly the best known Erlang application so far.

Why Erlang ? From the [overview](http://couchdb.apache.org/docs/overview.html) (worth reading in full):

> The document, view, security and
>   replication models, the special
>   purpose query language, the efficient
>   and robust disk layout and the
>   concurrent and reliable nature of the
>   Erlang platform are all carefully
>   integrated for a reliable and
>   efficient system.

Comment: For **some** of their telecomms systems.

Comment: CouchDB is not an OO database, it's a document-oriented database.

Comment: @I GIVE TERRIBLE ADVICE - yes, of course. Corrected. I would change your moniker :-)

Comment: There was an earlier concurrency language used by Ericsson called PLEX (Programming Language for Exchanges), which ran digital telephone exchanges throughout the late 80's until now. I think erlang is a refined version of PLEX.

Answer (score 15):

I came across this is in the process of writing up a report: [Erlang in Acoustic Ray Tracing](http://homepage.cs.uri.edu/faculty/hamel/pubs/icfp08.pdf).

It's an experience report on a research group's attempt to use Erlang for Acoustic Ray Tracing. They found that while it was easier to write the program, less buggy, etc. It scaled worse, and performed 10x slower than a comparable C program. So one spot where it may not be well suited is CPU intensive scenarios.

Do note though, that the people wrote the paper were in the stages of first learning Erlang, and may not have known the proper development procedures for CPU intensive Erlang.

Comment: The paper is an interesting read.  It doesn't directly make that generalization about suitability, it indicates that they found Erlang to unsuitable if you are trying to deploy on an IBM Cell BE processor, found in the Playstation 3.  It also states they are inexperienced with Erlang.  With more experience and suitable hardware they may have arrived at a different conclusion.  I get the impression that their code may have included use of non-tail-recursive functions ; if so then it may go some way to explaining their problems with memory, garbage collection, crashes and performance.

Comment: I think you misread the article. The inability to run on a Cell processor was unfortunate, but it was only a side note. The 12x performance difference between a C++ and an Erlang implementation running on an x86 platform was the real problem, combined with the fact that it didn't scale linearly. That said, they were new to the language, and may have taken a few unwise code paths... such is life. I'm curious about the non-linear scaling though.

Comment: I stand corrected on the 12x performance issue with regards to the Intel versus Cell, but I maintain that Erlang can be well suited to CPU challenging scenarios. That's not to say they aren't right : this really might be a problem where a good C++ solution will always beat a good Erlang solution. Perhaps this does go some way towards serving as a reminder to some folks that Erlang, like any other technology, is no silver bullet and it will only shine when used the right way in the right place.

Answer (score 14):

Apparently, Yahoo used Erlang to make something it calls Harvester. Article about it here: http://www.ddj.com/architect/220600332

Comment: Reading from the article: "While Harvester was originally written in Perl, Erlang's high-level concurrency constructs -- along with OTP design principles -- make it an ideal platform for building reliable, fault tolerant, and scalable applications like Harvester. The resulting service is more scalable, available, reliable, and able to comply with tighter service-level agreements (SLA) on a lighter code base and less expensive development efforts.". Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 11):

What is erlang good for?

http://beebole.com/en/blog/erlang/why-erlang/

http://www.aquabu.com/2008/2/15/erlang-pragmatic-studio-day-3-notes

http://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/9q0lr/erlang_and_highfrequency_trading/
(jerf's answer)

It's important to realize that Erlang's 4 parts: the language itself, the VMs(BEAM, hipe) standard libs (plus modules on github, CEAN, etc.) and development environment are being steadily updated / expanded/improved.  For example, i remember reading that the floating point performance improved when Wings3d's author realized it needed to improve (I can't find a source for this). And this guy just wrote about it:

http://marian-dan.com/wordpress/?p=324

A couple years ago, Tim Bray's Wide Finder publicity and all the folks starting to do web app frameworks and HTTP servers lead (at least in part) to improved regex and binaries handling. And there's all the work integrating HiPE and SMP, the dialyzer project, multiple unit testing and build libs springing up, ..

So its sweet spot is expanding,  The difficult thing is that the official docs can't keep up very well, and the mailing list and erlang blogosphere volume are growing quickly

Answer (score 10):

We are using Erlang to provide the back-end muscle power for our really real-time browser-based multi-player game [Pixza](http://pixza.com). We don't use Flash or any other third-party plugins, though the game is real-time multi-player. We use pure JS and COMET techniques instead. And Erlang supports the "really realtimeliness" of Pixza.

Answer (score 10):

I'm working for wooga, a social game company and we use Erlang for some of our game backends (basically http apis for millions of daily users) and auxiliary services like ios push notification provider, payment etc.

I think it really shines in network related tasks and it makes it kind of straight forward to structure and implement simple and complex network services alike in it. Distribution, fault tolerance and performance are easy to achieve because Erlang already has some of the key ingredients built in and they are being used for a long time in critical production infrastructure. So its not like "the new hip technology thing 0.0.2 alpha".

I know that other game companies use Erlang as well. You should be able to find presentations on slideshare about that.

Answer (score 6):

Erlang draws its strength from being a functional language with no shared memory. Hence IMO, Erlang won't be suitable for applications that require in place memory manipulations. Image editing for example.